# Handling duplicates in intersection of multi-dimensional list

Tags: python, list, intersection

Here is my code:

```py
List_of_list=[[1,2,3,4,5,5], [1,2,3,5,5], [1,3,5,5]]
```

When I am using the intersection function, it is showing me the result: `[1,3,5]`. But **5** is repeated **2** times in all inner lists. How can I get two **5**'s in my answer?

Comment: how are you doing intersection ?

Comment: Result= set(List_of_list[0]).intersection(*List_of_list[1:])

Comment: muultiple list intersection doesn;t work this way, plus if there aqre duplcate item then set is not right way

Answer (score 1):

A set can only have 1 element of each type (no repeated elements).
If you want a set with repetitions, you can use a multiset:

```
from multiset import Multiset as mset

List_of_list=[[1,2,3,4,5,5],[1,2,3,5,5],[1,3,5,5]]

sets=[mset(x) for x in List_of_list]

ms=mset.intersection(*sets)

print(ms)
>>>{1, 3, 5, 5}
```